# Admob - Controlling ad types

Tags: android, admob

I am using admob in my android app and I noticed that the ads that are displayed has nothing to do with the content of the app. I tried adding keywords to the adrequest but nothing changed.On what basis does admob display ads in an app?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using AdMob, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is slightly outdated so I thought I'd add a new one:

Monetise -> Select your app from the list -> Click 'Allow & block ads' tab

Here you have 'General categories' and 'Sensitive categories' and you can Allow/Block whichever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Manage Settings button for the app, then change the Ad Filters, mainly Catagory/Type settings

Comment: I only blocked ads related to gambling and relegion, but I am only getting one ad all the time, my app is about recipes and the app is about booking

Comment: Is the one ad a test ad or a live ad?  Do you have AdSense backfill enabled (this will drastically improve fill rate)?  If you have a newly created pub id, it can take some time/multiple requests before you start receiving live ads.